# In MVC3 how to perform remote validation on Edit action?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, duplicates, action

I read this useful example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2 for remote validation in MVC3, and it works great when I create a new item; however, I'm in trouble when I try to edit a newly created item.

I have a Model like this

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Language

    Public Property LanguageId As Integer

    <Display(Name:="DisplayNameLanguageName", ResourceType:=GetType(Resources.Language)),
        Required(ErrorMessageResourceName:="ErrorMessageLanguageNameRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType:=GetType(Resources.Language)),
        StringLength(20),
        Remote("IsNameAvailable", "Language", "AdminArea", ErrorMessageResourceName:="ErrorMessageNameNotAvailable", ErrorMessageResourceType:=GetType(Resources.Language))>
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Flag as String    
End Class
```

In the Controller "Language" class I have...

```
   'OutputCache needed for remote validation
   <OutputCache(Location:=OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore:=True)>
    Public Class LanguageController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Private db As StoreEntities = New StoreEntities

        'remote validation for duplicates
        Public Function IsNameAvailable(Name As String) As JsonResult
            Return Json(Not db.Languages.Any(Function(x) x.Name = Name), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        End Function

[...]
```

From the View "Create.vbhtml", I can create a new language, but from "Edit.vbhtml" I can't edit only the Flag property leaving the same value for the Name because validation starts. I'm forced to change Name property too.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem adding an hidden field "HiddenName" with name of the language as value in the Edit.vbhtml View and editing the validation function in the Controller like this

```
Public Function IsNameAvailable(Name As String, Optional HiddenName As String = "") As JsonResult
    If Name <> HiddenName Then
        Return Json(Not db.Languages.Any(Function(x) x.Name = Name), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    Else
        Return Json(True, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End If
End Function
```